# How to make two actions to work together in Struts 2

Tags: java, design-patterns, struts2, post-redirect-get

I need to load some data from a table to show in a JSP page.

Then, when the user pushes on a button, they'll send the form to save in a database.

I wonder if I can create a method to load the `init` data only (I don't want to call the method execute, which will save the data).

I've tried it with implements `Preparable` but it calls execute method. In Struts2 I have a method called init to load data but I can't do it in Struts2.

What should I do, create an action to load data (loading with execute method) and another action to save data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a method in action class call it whatever you want and map this method to the action. This method should return a JSP page as a result. All you have configure in the same file. `prepare` is extremely useful when you need to return a result without action execution, like an input result when validation fails.

In Struts2 every request that is mapped by the filter is an action and it has an action context. A request has two methods that most popular `GET` and `POST`. You create two separate actions for GET and POST request. This is actually needed to follow [PRG pattern](http://www.theserverside.com/news/1365146/Redirect-After-Post).

Answer (score 0):

An **action** is a **method** of a **class** mapped by Struts (in struts.xml, or with annotation).

You can map only the class, and hence the `execute()` method will be used. But nothing prevent you to have multiple methods in a single class and make them different actions. The action is the method, not the file.

For example, if you need one action to read and another to write, both of the following ways are correct:

1. Two different files:

   ```java
   public class ReadAction extends ActionSupport {
       public String execute(){ ... }
   }

   public class WriteAction extends ActionSupport {
       public String execute(){ ... }
   }
   ```

   ```xml
   <action name="read" class="foo.bar.ReadAction">
       <result>page.jsp</result>
   </action>

   <action name="write" class="foo.bar.WriteAction">
       <result>page.jsp</result>
   </action>
   ```
2. Two different methods in the same file:

   ```java
   public class ReadWriteAction extends ActionSupport {
       public String read(){ ... }
       public String write(){ ... }
   }
   ```

   ```xml
   <action name="read" class="foo.bar.ReadWriteAction" method="read">
       <result>page.jsp</result>
   </action>

   <action name="write" class="foo.bar.ReadWriteAction" method="write">
       <result>page.jsp</result>
   </action>
   ```

It's obvios that if you have code in commons between the actions, to avoid redundance, you need to join them somehow:

- a BaseAction extended by both of them, or
- a method in the class where both of the actions are.

The method can be whatever you want. The `prepare()` method is a special method run by the PrepareInterceptor on actions implementing the Preparable interface that can be useful to pre-load data, for example when validation fails.

How to design your application is up to you, but if you have two logical actions, one to load and present data in a page, and another to write the data, and then again load it and present it in a page, you need two actions (**load** and **write**) and a [PRG pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) (`->` means `returns`) :

> - Load  `->` JSP
> - Write `->` (redirectAction) Load `->` JSP